# Proving that $SU(n)$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

We know that, for $U(n)$, every unitary matrix has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, with eigenvalues of the form $e^{i \theta}$. We can decompose it in its eigenbasis and define a path such that $f:I \longrightarrow U(n)$ that satisfies the following: $f(0) = U$ and $ f(1) = I$. Thus any $2$ elements $U$ and $V$ of $U(n)$ can be connected to each other by a continuos path.

Can we do a similar procedure to prove that $SU(n)$ is connected? If so how?

Comment: Can't you just deform the eigenvalues to all be 1 while keeping their product 1? Do it iteratively, fixing one you've already made 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A,B\in SU(n)$ and consider a path $\gamma:[0,1]\to U(n)$ joining $A$ to $B$. As you've pointed out, the determinant of a unitary matrix $V$ is a complex number of norm $1$ and therefore $R_{V}= \begin{pmatrix}\frac1{\det V}&0\\ 0& I_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}$ is unitary. Now the path $\rho(t)=R_{\gamma(t)}\gamma(t)$ is in $SU(n)$ and it joins $A$ to $B$.

Comment: By the notation used, at any particular instant $t$ we have a matrix from $U(n)$  correct? For instance: $ \rho( t_0=0) = R_A A$  and that gives a matrix that has determinant 1, right?

Comment: $\gamma(t)$ is in $U(n)$ for all $t$. $\rho(t)$ is of course in $U(n)$ as well; however if you compute $\det\rho(t)$ with Binet you'll realize that actually $\rho(t)\in SU(n)$. Also, note that $\rho(0)=R_AA=A$.